# struct buffer_head inefficiency

Tags: linux, operating-system, kernel, block

Can anybody tell the reason why the struct buffer_head structure which were used till Linux Kernel 2.4 is inefficient and what things are implemented in the struct bio structure used in the new redesigned block layer from kernel 2.5.1 ?

Answer (score 6):

In pre-2.5 kernels, buffer_head used to be *the* unit of IO . However, doing IO in terms of buffer_head can be inefficient. For example, a single write spanning multiple blocks would result in creation of multiple buffer_head objects, thus wasting space and time. So, a **buffer_head struct is best used for providing the block-to-physical memory mapping**, which is exactly what it does (and the *only* thing that it does) from 2.5 kernel onwards.

---

On the other hand, **struct bio is designed to be the unit of IO in later kernel releases.** ****It represents the *active* IOs currently in the kernel**.** Note that the mapping of block-to-memory is still maintained in buffer_head. However, the buffer_head is now not overloaded with the fields that contain info about currently active IO. So, when higher level code such as filesystem, issues an IO, a request is added to the request_queue. The request in turn contains a pointer to the bio structure. The device driver that controls the device on which IO is issued, picks up the request and serves it.

The struct bio structure is also used for splitting IOs, for example, by RAID disk device drivers. Look at the struct bio definition and you will find that it maintains an array of io_vectors (which are nothing but offsets into memory pages). Also, bi_idx is used to index into these io_vec. By using a different bi_idx value for different disk, each disk will pick up a different set of io_vec to write (or read), and thus the IO would be done in a true parallel fashion.

Comment: I'm currently running kernel 5.4 and according to `slabtop` my `buffer_head` count is about 50% of the `ext4_inode_cache` count. Is this expected nowadays? I'd have assumed from the above explanation that `buffer_head` usage should be pretty low nowadays. My system is suffering from some latency issues and I'm trying to find the cause.

Answer (score 2):

Use the source, luke !

From `include/linux/buffer_head.h`:

```
/*
 * Historically, a buffer_head was used to map a single block
 * within a page, and of course as the unit of I/O through the
 * filesystem and block layers.  Nowadays the basic I/O unit
 * is the bio, and buffer_heads are used for extracting block
 * mappings (via a get_block_t call), for tracking state within
 * a page (via a page_mapping) and for wrapping bio submission
 * for backward compatibility reasons (e.g. submit_bh).
 */
struct buffer_head {
[ ... ]
```

And from `linux/include/bio.h`:

```
/*
 * main unit of I/O for the block layer and lower layers (ie drivers and
 * stacking drivers)
 */
struct bio {
[ ... ]
```

The two decouple I/O characteristics and operations for "higher levels" (I/O through filesystems) and "low levels" (I/O through block devs). This allows for higher performance because a buffer layer waiting somewhere doesn't stop the block layer from performing work elsewhere. Some explanation about it can be found [here](http://lse.sourceforge.net/io/bionotes.txt), and Jens Axboe talks about it [in this interview](http://kerneltrap.org/node/7637) briefly.

Comment: Answer merely provides a description of the structures, but does not really explain *why* one is less efficient than the other. Also, the interview link is now broken, which is the *primary reason* answers are not supposed to do this...

Answer (score 1):

Robert Love's LKD 3rd have a very detail explanation on this.

> **The Old Versus the New**
>
> The difference between buffer heads and the new 
>   bio structure is important.The bio structure represents an I/O
>   operation, which may include one or more pages in memory. On the other
>   hand, the buffer_head structure represents a single buffer, which
>   describes a single block on the disk. Because buffer heads are tied to
>   a single disk block in a single page, buffer heads result in the
>   unnecessary dividing of requests into block-sized chunks, only to
>   later reassemble them. Because the bio structure is lightweight, it
>   can describe discontiguous blocks and does not unnecessarily split I/O
>   operations. Switching from struct buffer_head to struct bio provided
>   other benefits, as well:
>
> - The bio structure can easily represent high memory, because struct bio
>     deals with only physical pages and not direct pointers.
> - The bio structure can represent both normal page I/O and direct I/O (I/O
>     opera- tions that do not go through the page cache—see Chapter 16,“The
>     Page Cache and Page Writeback,” for a discussion on the page cache).
> - The bio structure makes it easy to perform scatter-gather (vectored)
>     block I/O operations, with the data involved in the operation
>     originating from multiple physi- cal pages.
> - The bio structure is much
>     more lightweight than a buffer head because it contains only the
>     minimum information needed to represent a block I/O operation and not
>     unnecessary information related to the buffer itself.